# How to 'Create a table based on a query and delete from first 3 characters to the right'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simply query:

```
select pcode, description from outerb where pcode like '123%'
```

Here is a fiddle link to show you where I got to:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf44b07918374985074084552e7b7005

How would I create a new table based on the query above, but removing all characters to the right from 3rd character?

This is my expected output

```
pcode   description 
123        TEST     
123        TEST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring(string, start, length)`

```
SELECT substring(pcode, 1, 3) AS pcode,
       description,
       size
FROM table1
```

Comment: thanks Cid, does `1, 3` simply mean start from 1 and end at 3?

Comment: Starts at 1 and has 3 length

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `left()` function:

```
select left(pcode, 3) as pcode, description, size
from table1;
```

Comment: This one should have been the accepted answer, `left()` is more appropriate in this case than `substring()`